# ng-click event showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Button 1 - >

```
 <button id="btn1" ng-click="bubbleInfo($event)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>
```

Button 2

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" ng-click="bubbleInfo($event)"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>
```

When i clicked Button 1, in console.log i am getting proper id as btn1, but when i clicked on button 2 i am getting undefined. The only changes in Button 1  and in Button 2 is class="btn btn-primary" is at last and in button 2 class i mentioned at starting only. what is the reason i am getting undefined at second case (Button 2)

```
 $scope.bubbleInfo = function (event) {
        console.log(event.target.id); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Will you share some HTML to see where the buttons are placed?

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fgc21e86/10/

Comment: @Mistalis Hi Sir , <button id="{{bubble.Id}}" ng-click="bubbleInfo($event)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button> When i click on the button i am getting button id , but when i click on  "<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>" this icon, i am getting undefined, if i replace <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> with text its working fine

Comment: @Mistalis For the reference i added image also and this is the html code <button id="{{bubble.Id}}" ng-click="bubbleInfo($event)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>

Answer (score 0):

Try to add followings to cancel event bubbling and capturing and prevent default behavour

```
$scope.bubbleInfo = function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.id); 
}
```